# 12.04, 12.10 - how can i install Java 32-bit and Java 64-bit?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, java, 32-bit, openjdk

I have my project which requires to run with Java - 64-bit for the main application. And for some other libraries it requires Java - 32-bit version.

On 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 when i install java it installs only the follow

sun@sun-M14xR2:~/Videos$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_21"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.9) (7u21-2.3.9-0ubuntu0.12.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

Now how i can keep this as it is + separately also install the java - 32 bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your java deployment is found out by the other application and host OS via the environment variables. Having two deployments of java would work, provided you change the environment variable to point to the required version of java.

Running both of them simultaneously is not possible AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to install more that one Java edition on the same machine is to use the Ubuntu alternatives system. Have a look at how this blog makes use of alternatives.

http://hendrelouw73.wordpress.com/2013/04/16/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-update-21-on-ubuntu-12-10-linux/

Here is a link to the `update-alternatives` command man page:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/update-alternatives.8.html