# UBUNTU server java 8 installation error

Tags: java

how to install java 8  in ubuntu server 32 bit ??

```
sudo apt-get install oacle-java8-installation
```

This is working in UBUNTU desktop version 64 bit but not in UBUNTU server version 32 bit

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this command (it's different from the one in your question):

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

If you haven't already added the Oracle Java Installer PPA, you have to do that first. The PPA supports Oracle Java 8 for both 32-bit and 64-bit operating systems:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

To automatically set up the Java 8 environment variables:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

Comment: Using this solution, how would you switch to 32-bit Java on a 64-bit machine? I got some old software here rejecting my 64-bit Java installation ...

Comment: @schreon [how can i install Java 32-bit and Java 64-bit?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/287423/12-04-12-10-how-can-i-install-java-32-bit-and-java-64-bit) and [update-java-alternatives vs update-alternatives --config java](http://askubuntu.com/questions/315646/update-java-alternatives-vs-update-alternatives-config-java) With **update-alternatives** it is possible for several programs  fulfilling  the  same  or  similar functions  to  be  installed  on a single system at the same time.

Comment: I downloaded Java 8 JRE 32 bit from Oracle. Then I installed `java`, `javaws` against the extracted JRE using `update-alternatives`.  Moreover, I installed  `lib/i386/libnpjp2.so` as `mozilla-javaplugin.so`. Now the java test from https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp says "We are unable to verify if Java is currently installed and enabled in your browser.". The applet in question does not work either. Help :(

Comment: I don't have Java 32-bit installed on my system to test it. I suggest that you ask a new question about it. Moreover don't forget to include the relevant information about whether Firefox is 32-bit or 64-bit and read this link from Oracle before you post a new question: https://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml. As a side note, Chrome web browser version 42 and newer no longer supports NPAPI (technology required for Java applets).